# How to strip illegal characters from FOR XML PATH query in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, for-xml-path

I have a SQL Server table that I extract data from as XML in the form

```
SELECT * FROM myTable FOR XML PATH( 'myElement' ), ROOT( 'myDocument' ), TYPE
```

Somehow a user has managed to get a control character into a free text field (Ctrl-V) and this means the query above fails with an error:

```
FOR XML could not serialize the data for node 'MYFIELDNAME' because it contains a character
(0x0016) which is not allowed in XML. To retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it into
binary, varbinary, or use the BINARY BASE64 directive.
```

Since I am expecting that the data is text, I don't want to convert it into a binary form, but to strip out any non-valid XML characters at source.

I found the following on SO:

[How to make FOR XML PATH not choke on ASCII Control Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049847/how-to-make-for-xml-path-not-choke-on-ascii-control-codes)

but it doesn't help as it doesn't solve the original question asked, but corrects the OP's misreading of the XML specification.

Is there any of globally directing SQL-Server to strip invalid characters, rather than generating this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Replace invalid XML characters from a VARCHAR(MAX) field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365316/sql-server-replace-invalid-xml-characters-from-a-varcharmax-field)

Comment: There is no global setting to do this. You'll have to replace characters in individual fields. The linked duplicate has one approach to doing this. From 2017 onwards, `TRANSLATE` can simplify mass replacing characters.

Comment: Also, of course, it's time to add a check constraint on that column to prevent any characters below 0x20 being contained in there (except tab, cr, lf probably)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks! I don't think this is a duplicate, as it's not really related to the NVARCHAR/VARCHAR issue. The problem with the suggested solution, is that `<test>&#x16;</test>` isn't valid XML and will not parse. (I've edited the question to add TYPE to my SQL as I am using TYPE in my queries.)

Comment: Yeah, if you absolutely need typed XML the only solution is to replace the characters XML doesn't like in the string, before XML conversion. This necessarily means abandoning `SELECT *` and slapping together a function for replacing/stripping the unwanted characters from `NVARCHAR` to `NVARCHAR` so you can apply it to individual character fields. ...are you sure you don't want to move to JSON instead? :-P

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's what I was afraid of. Damien_The_Unbeliever's suggestion would be great but sadly I don't have that sort of control of the database. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use code to strip the chars before the conversion to XML.
I would typically do this via CTE using the following logic, then use FOX XML on the cte.

This wouldn't be the most efficient but would do the trick:

```
    Select @FileDatePart = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Getdate(), 22)

    Select @FileDatePart = Replace(@FileDatePart, a.search, a.replace)
    From (
    Values ( '/', '' )
    ,      ( ':', '' )
    ,      ( ' ', '' )

    ) As a([Search], [Replace])
```

To use the ascii codes

```
    Select @FileDatePart = Replace(@FileDatePart, a.search, a.replace)
    From (
    Values (char(47), '' )
    ,      ( char(58), '' )
    ,      ( char(32), '' )

    ) As a([Search], [Replace])
```

For a table of ASCII values

```
DECLARE @i INTEGER = 0
DECLARE @j INTEGER = 0
DECLARE @Step INTEGER = 16
DECLARE @Lim INTEGER = 255
DECLARE @aLine VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Dec VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT  @Dec += 'Declare @i AS INTEGER = 1' + CHAR(13) + 'Declare @step as integer = ' + CAST(@Step AS VARCHAR(25)) + CHAR(13) + 'While @i * @Step < ' + CAST(@Lim AS VARCHAR(25)) + ' Begin  '
                + CHAR(13)

WHILE(@i < @Step)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @i += 1
        SELECT  @aLine =
            @aLine + ' @i -1 + ' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(25)) + ' as Col' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(25)) + ', Isnull(cast(char(@i +' + CAST(@i - 1 AS VARCHAR(25)) + ') as Varchar(25)),''*NA*'') as VAL'
            + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(25)) + CASE
                                            WHEN @i < @Step THEN ','
                                            ELSE ''
                                        END
    END

SELECT  @i = 1
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Select ' + REPLACE(@aLine, '@i', CAST(@i + @j AS VARCHAR(5)))

SELECT  @i += @Step
WHILE @i <= @Lim
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @output += CHAR(13) + 'union Select ' + REPLACE(@aLine, '@i', CAST(@i + @j AS VARCHAR(5)))
        SELECT  @i += @Step
    END
EXEC(@output)
GO
```

Comment: I didn't think a space char is an illegal XML char